# svg scaling with jquery

Tags: jquery, svg, web

i am developing a website but i am not that good at the UI part, anyway i have managed to get an SVG file from illustrator then using jquery i am manipulating it, however it doesn't show properly on browsers, the SVG is bigger than the "preview" on adobe illustrator, the preview on adobe use `<object>` but in JQUERY i am loading the svg file directly

here is the head of my svg file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 
    6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1024 768" 
    style="width:1024;height:768;">
```

and here is start of my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-
 1.0.1.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $.get('new.svg', function(data) {
 $(document.body).append(data.documentElement);
 $('#TESTGROUPCIRCLE').on('click touchstart', function () {
 $('#tooltip').hide();
 $('#TESTTEXT').fadeIn();
 $('#MAIN').fadeOut();
  });
```

i am not sure why the svg shows larger when i get it directly without using `<object>` , it shows at 1333 * 999 for a reason i don't know, anybody came across such a problem before?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the img tag with `style="width:1024;height:768"` to display the svg in the correct dimensions. 
You are appending the svg right onto the body without having an img tag.
As far as I can see your new.svg is at the same source. So there should be no need to load it with jQuery.

Comment: Greetings, and sorry for late response, i tried loading with img tag but i couldn't manipulate the svg document elements like i did when i loaded it directly with JQUERY, i am sorry i know i am kind of a newbie to web, what i am trying to do is make the svg adjustable to any browser while take over the whole page, i am designing an svg based landing page, do you think i should make width and height smaller from adobe illustrator or it doesn't matter?